# R Gui crashes with Keras Tensorflow windows cuda gpu

Tags: r, tensorflow, crash, keras

edit: solved.  I was not using the proper version of
cudnn. After downloading and copying over cuDNN v5.1 Library for Windows 10, everything works fine so far. I should have followed tensorflow windows [guidelines](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_windows) more
closely.

---

I just spent some time to set up a windows system to run
r-tensorflow with keras and tensorflow as a backend.

I followed these [blog](https://mpopov.com/blog/r-win-gpu-tensorflow) instructions, and I am able to get the hello world example to work. However, when I continue to some R keras [examples](https://rstudio.github.io/keras/articles/examples/mnist_cnn.html)
, several will just crash and exit RGui during running the training phase,
e.g. mnist_cnn fails at the training model block.

```
# train and evaluate
model %>% fit(
  x_train, y_train,
  batch_size = batch_size,
  epochs = epochs,
  verbose = 1,
  validation_data = list(x_test, y_test)
)
```

A Visual Studio JIT popup shows "An unhandled win32 exception occured in Rgui.exe[10456]." And VS editor shows, "Unhandled exception at 0x00007FFFEA2734BE (ucrtbase.dll) in Rgui.exe: Fatal program exit requested."

There is very little load on CPU and or GPU during runtime
(less than 30%).  Any ideas on how to further debug are appreciated.

```
Hardware/Software/Setup:
windows 10 Pro 64 bit OS x64 cpu
intel i7-7700 @3.60GHz
64G ram
R 64 bit 3.4.1
Anaconda 3/Python 3.5.4
Nvidia 1060 6G
CUDA 8.0 V8.0.60
Visual Studio 2015 community edition
```

using

```
library(tensorflow)
use_condaenv("r-tensorflow")
library(keras)
```

---

I also just ran in Rstudio w/ rdesktop log diagnostics on the file and got the following log after crash (I see it cannot find file, but not certain what file).

```
20 Aug 2017 01:29:32 [rdesktop] ERROR system error 2 (The system cannot find the file specified); 
OCCURRED AT: virtual void rstudio::core::http::NamedPipeAsyncClient::connectAndWriteRequest() C:/Users/Administrator/rstudio/src/cpp/core/include/core/http/NamedPipeAsyncClient.hpp:84; 
LOGGED FROM: void rstudio::desktop::NetworkReply::onError(const rstudio::core::Error&) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\desktop\DesktopNetworkReply.cpp:288
20 Aug 2017 01:29:42 [rdesktop] ERROR system error 2 (The system cannot find the file specified); 
OCCURRED AT: virtual void rstudio::core::http::NamedPipeAsyncClient::connectAndWriteRequest() C:/Users/Administrator/rstudio/src/cpp/core/include/core/http/NamedPipeAsyncClient.hpp:84; 
LOGGED FROM: void rstudio::desktop::NetworkReply::onError(const rstudio::core::Error&) C:\Users\Administrator\rstudio\src\cpp\desktop\DesktopNetworkReply.cpp:288
```

edit: stepping through several more exampes, several seem to work fine -- it could just be specific to the particular code and my setup. I don't know enough right now to troubleshoot the code ideosyncracies. Those that crash also seem to do so at the model fitting stage.  I'll update a list on crash/no-crash as I test. pass = no-crash, fail = crash and exit

```
mnist_hierarchical_rnn    # pass

mnist_transfer_cnn  # fail

variational_autoencoder_deconv # fail

stateful_lstm   # pass

variational_autoencoder # pass

reuters_mlp  # pass

mnist_mlp  # pass

mnist_irnn # pass

mnist_cnn # fail

mnist_antirectifier  # fail
```

Comment: Are you running R line by line or as a script?

Comment: tried both. I can run the mnist_cnn example up to the #train eval model fit block. Works fine till then, and crashes during model fitting.